# How to define new resolvers?

Tags: sbt

I have defined several additional resolvers, which are displayed by `resolvers`:

```
[clearspan]> show resolvers
[info] List(bt: http://maven.[redacted].com/artifactory/repo/, Local Maven Repository: file:///home/dan/.m2/repository, Oracle: http://download.java.net/maven/2, localMaven: file:///home/dan/.m2/repository)
```

However, when I run `update`, it only tries `Maven Central`.  Any idea why?

```
> update
[info] Updating {file:/home/dan/l/clearspan/}cs-trading-processor...
[warn]  [NOT FOUND  ] javax.resource#connector;1.0!connector.jar (44ms)
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/resource/connector/1.0/connector-1.0.jar
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: javax.resource#connector;1.0!connector.jar
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[info] 
[warn] :: problems summary ::
[warn] :::: WARNINGS
[warn]      [NOT FOUND  ] javax.resource#connector;1.0!connector.jar (44ms)
[warn]  ==== public: tried
[warn]    http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/resource/connector/1.0/connector-1.0.jar
[warn]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]      ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[warn]      :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[warn]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]      :: javax.resource#connector;1.0!connector.jar
[warn]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[info] 
[info] :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
[error] {file:/home/dan/l/[redacted]/}[redacted]/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: download failed: javax.resource#connector;1.0!connector.jar
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Sep 7, 2011 4:51:11 PM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have been setting `externalResolvers` instead.

Answer (score 5):

According to the documentation [Library dependencies](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Library-Dependencies.html) section [Resolvers](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Library-Dependencies.html#Resolvers):

> Not all packages live on the same server; sbt uses the standard Maven2
>   repository by default. If your dependency isn’t on one of the default
>   repositories, you’ll have to add a `resolver` to help Ivy find it.

You can do it using `resolvers` setting:

```
resolvers += name at location
```

You did it and it didn't work.

In [Overriding default resolvers](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Library-Dependencies.html#Overriding+default+resolvers) you can read:

> `resolvers` does not contain the default resolvers; only additional ones
>   added by your build definition.
>
> sbt combines resolvers with some default repositories to form
>   `externalResolvers`.
>
> Therefore, to change or remove the default resolvers, you would need
>   to override `externalResolvers` instead of `resolvers`.

In your answer you said using `externalResolvers` helped, but I doubt that (sorry).

I think the issue was where you defined the new `resolvers`. It appears that the resolvers come from the top-level project while you may have been using multi-project build and the `resolvers` setting didn't get picked up.

I think a solution is to define the `resolvers` setting for the build in general using `in ThisBuild` or `in [projectName]` for a given project with `projectName` replaced with the proper project name the value of the setting should be set to.